# error with python + lxml: xsltStylePreCompute: unknown xsl:result-document

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xslt, lxml

I'm running into this strange error when using Python with lxml. The error message is as follows:

````
autoapi.xsl:60:0:ERROR:XSLT:ERR_OK: compilation error, element 'result-document'```

XSLT file at line 60 is as follows:
```<xsl:result-document .... indent="yes" method="xml" href="{$filename}">```

Note: the doctype-public and the doctype-system attributes have been properly set.
````

Answer (score 0):

The `xsl:result-document` instruction requires a processor that supports XSLT 2.0. The `libxslt` processor supports only XSLT 1.0.

However, you should be able to create multiple result documents using either the [EXSLT  `exsl:document` extension element](http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html) or the [XSLT 1.1  `xsl:document` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/#output).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed the xslt and used xsl:documented. The error message is gone but the resultant document is not getting created.